# WordPress category based template

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a task to create a template which is specific to the category. So Lets say I have 10 categories but I want to create a specific template for lets say 3 of them. So if the category is a,b or c I will apply a certain template.

And then when I create a post and attach it to the specific category I need to show that specific template associated to the category.

Any headers?

Comment: @ali this may help https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-category-template/

Comment: Thanks @shashi I will check it out.

Comment: See my answer for 2 different solutions, both of which have been tested. https://stackoverflow.com/a/46639563/4643292

Comment: @shashi I tried the plugin, I am using click mag theme and its not working with that one. the template doesn't update. I guess I will have to work with some other options.

Comment: This question already exists in wordpress exchange
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169831/custom-single-template-for-a-specific-category

Answer (score 0):

The Advanced Custom Fields https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/ plugin should allow you to show different templates based off categories. It has some pretty fancy functionality, but can't remember if it can do exactly this.

There is a free version, so give it a try. Let me know how you go ;)

Answer (score 0):

1. Delete everything in single.php
2. Insert the ‘switching’ code (see below)
3. Create 3(three) new templates with unique names. like : single-a,single-b,single-c.
4. On the server, the magical fairy dust in your modified single.php will automatically load the correct template when the page is requested

Please try below Code for the same.

```
if (in_category('21')) {include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-a.php');
}
else if (in_category('22')) {include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-b.php');
}
else if (in_category('23')) {include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-c.php');
}
else { include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-29.php');
}
```

There is single-a,single-b,single-c are 3 templates for different categories and your main code in it.

Comment: Here we are not discussing about post we are discussing about the category so according to me single.php must not come over here . it will must be category-a.php and so on

Comment: @Akshay Shah : Please read question carefully. i mean this line  : "And then when I create a post and attach it to the specific category I need to show that specific template associated to the category"

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to [Category_Templates](https://codex.wordpress.org/Category_Templates)

Wordpress will auto retrieve category files in the following format:

`category-slug.php` or `category-ID.php`

Let's say you have 3 categories, **category a**, **category b**, **category c**, to assign each of the template differently you can easily create **category-a.php**, **category-b.php**, **category-c.php** and place your desire template within the file and Wordpress will handle the rest.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can use `category_template`

```
function wp_category_template( $template ) {
    $cat = get_queried_object(); // get category object
    if( 1 ) // check condition 
        $template = locate_template( 'template.php' ); // load template
    return $template;
}
add_filter( 'category_template', 'wp_category_template' );
```

or as @shashi suggested you can use plugin [custom-category-template](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-category-template/)

Answer (score 0):

You have 3 options :

**Option 1 :** You can create 3 templates and name them according to the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/) like this :

- category-1.php
- category-2.php
- category-3.php

**Option 2 :** Use PHP code in your functions file to load 1 template for 3 different categories :

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'custom_category_template', 99 );

function custom_category_template( $template ) {

    if ( is_category(array( 1,2,3 )  )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'custom.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template;
        }
    }

    return $template;
}
```

Use the [in_category or is_category conditional tag](https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags#A_Category_Page) depending on whether you want to load the template for posts in specific categories or only for the category archive page.

**Option 3 :** You can use the code in option 2 with the [category_template filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/category_template) :

```
add_filter( 'category_template', 'custom_category_template' );
function custom_category_template( $template ) {

      if ( is_category(array( 1,2,3 )  )  ) {

    $template = locate_template( 'custom.php' ); 
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Assumes your category i.d's are 1, 2 and 3. Swap out these to match your installations [category i.d's](https://wpsites.net/wordpress-tips/find-category-i-d/)